# Number Format Exception and Regex Inquiry

Tags: java, regex, arraylist, javafx, linked-list

I'm trying to take in a mathematical expression from the user, but I keep getting a Number Format Exception here:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "(13-1)*(12-10)"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
    at Main.lambda$start$2(Main.java:134)
    at Main$$Lambda$73/16094097.handle(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my Event-Handler that I am using to evaluate the expression entered. The text field is supposed to take in an expression of 4 numbers (1-13) and evaluate if it equals 24. I'm using a regular expression but it doesn't seem to be working. Also, I've got a character array that I was using at first for just the signs but that seems to not be necessary. I am very new to regex and have tried a number of combinations already.

```
btVerify.setOnAction(
            (ActionEvent e) -> 
            {
               LinkedList<Character> expInput = new LinkedList<Character>();
            for(char c: tfExpress.getText().toCharArray()){
                expInput.add(c);
                }
            String[] inputIntegers = tfExpress.getText().split("[^0-9]+-/*()");

               expInput.removeIf(p-> p.equals(signs));

            ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            for(String s:inputIntegers)
            {
               temp.add(new Integer(Integer.valueOf(s)));
            } 
            temp.remove(new Integer(card1.CardValue()));
            temp.remove(new Integer(card2.CardValue()));                    
            temp.remove(new Integer(card3.CardValue()));          
            temp.remove(new Integer(card4.CardValue()));          


               if(temp.isEmpty()&& expInput.isEmpty())
               {
                  if(express == 24){
                     display.setText("Correct");
                  }
                  else
                     display.setText("Incorrect");

               }
               else
                  display.setText("The numbers in the expression don't "
                     + "match the numbers in the set.");
            });
```

Comment: In addition to your regex, what are `signs`?

Comment: signs are a character arraylist I tried creating earlier. I left it in the code but it currently isn't working. I also experimented with just (temp.isEmpty()) in my if statement but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NumberFormat Exception` is because your regex doesn't separate the numbers from the signs/literals.

```
tfExpress.getText().split("[^0-9]+-/*()");
```

returns the whole text i.e. `(13-1)*(12-10)`

You need a more complex regex expression which will separate the signs from the numbers. Thanks to [@unihedron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3622940/unihedron) for the regex expression.

```
\b|(?<=[()])(?=[^\d()])|(?<=[^\d()])(?=[()])
```

Now you can use

```
...
String regex = "\b|(?<=[()])(?=[^\d()])|(?<=[^\d()])(?=[()])";
tfExpress.getText().split(regex);
...
```

A very simple working example can be [found here](https://regex101.com/r/cH3jL1/2).

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Any reason it would be telling me that "d" is an illegal escape character?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you don't expect to evaluate that formula with regex. That won't work.

For the splitting, if you don't know regex, use something else like the StringTokenizer.

```
StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer( "(13-1)*(12-10)", "+-/*()", true);
while( t.hasMoreTokens()) {
  System.out.println(t.nextToken());
}
```

results in

```
(
13
-
1
)
*
(
12
-
10
)
```

Comment: Ok thank you. How do I use this for an expression where I don't know the values? It's going to be different every time.